# Iron Router / User details issue in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron

I am relatively new to Meteor and have been stuck on an issue for awhile. I have a /users/:_id route that is supposed to display details specific to that user id. However, whenever I hit that route, it displays information for the currently logged in user, NOT of the user whose details I want to view.

Here's my route:

```
Router.route('/users/:_id', {name: 'Users', controller: 'usersDetailController'});
```

Here's my usersDetailController:

```
usersDetailController = RouteController.extend({
waitOn: function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('userProfileExtended', this.params._id);
},

onBeforeAction: function () {
    var currUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: currUserId});
    console.log('admin? ' + currUser.isAdmin);
    if (!currUser.isAdmin) {
        this.render('accessDenied');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},
action: function() {
    this.render('Users');
}
```

});

And here's my server/publish:

```
Meteor.publish('userProfileExtended', function() {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
```

});

User Details template:

```
<template name="Users">

<form>
{{#with user}}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{profile.companyName}} Details</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p><label>Company: </label><input id="Company" type="text" value={{profile.companyName}}></p>
                <p><label>Email: </label><input id="Email" type="text" value={{emails.address}}></p>
                <p><label>Phone: </label><input id="Phone" type="text" value={{profile.phoneNum}}></p>
                <p><label>Tire Markup: </label><input id = "tireMarkup" type="text" value={{profile.tireMarkup}}></p>
                <p><button class="saveUserDetails">Save</button></p>
                <p><button class="deleteUser">Delete User</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>


{{/with}}
```

Here's my Template Helper:

```
Template.Users.helpers({
user: function() { 
return Meteor.users.findOne();
}
```

});
Can someone help? I think the issue is the way i reference "this.userId"...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your publish function to use the `userId` parameter you specify when subscribing :

```
Meteor.publish('userProfileExtended', function(userId) {
  return Meteor.users.find(userId,{
    fields:{
      'username':1,
      'profile.firstName':1,
      'profile.lastName'
    }
  });
});
```

In the publish function, `userId` will equal whatever value you call `Meteor.subscribe` with, in this case it will hold `this.params._id`.

Beware of using the proper syntax for route parameters, if you declare a path of `/users/:_id`, you need to reference the param using `this.params._id`.

Also note that it's insecure to publish the whole user document to the client if you only need to show specific fields in the interface, that's why you want to use the `fields` option of `Collection.find` to only publish a subset of user documents.

EDIT :

I would recommend using the route `data` function to specify the data context you want to apply when rendering your template, something like this :

```
data: function(){
  return {
    user: Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id)
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the same issue... I also changed "this.params.id" to "this.params._id" in the subscription function. Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: also, wouldn't userId reference the logged in user?

Comment: Can you post the user detail template too ?

Comment: Where the user helper comes from ? Is it a helper declared on your template or is it referencing something you return from your route data function ?

Comment: I just added my helper template. Thanks!

Comment: The helper is likely the problem : using `findOne` you're returning ANY user available on the client, and it happens to be the currently logged in user, not the one you want to display details. Rework your code to get rid of this helper and use a data function in your route instead (edited my answer BTW).